# Modeling synchronization using actors

Tags: concurrency, actor

I'm trying to understand how to solve the [dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) using actors. In case you don't know, the crux of the problem is that a thread needs to obtain two locks before it can proceed...and there are multiple threads vying for these two locks.

Here's one way I can model this using actors:

```
# asynchronously request locks from 2 forks (both forks are actors)
lock1 = fork1.future.lock
lock2 = fork2.future.lock

if lock1 && lock2 # wait to get both locks
  ... critical section
end
```

But I think this will result in deadlock if two threads have one lock each and are waiting for the other thread to give up its lock.

In general, how would I model accessing two resources atomically using actors?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good implementation of a solution to this problem written in Scala using [Akka](http://akka.io/) actors [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-fsm/src/main/scala/DiningHakkersOnBecome.scala).

Comment: That looks correct, but the code would be the same if the chopsticks were mutexes instead of actors: 1. lock the `left` mutex. 2. try to lock the `right` mutex. If you succeed, eat! Otherwise, unlock the `left` mutex and try again. So could I say that actors don't provide anything special here?

Comment: By modelling the problem this way and using the states of the chopsticks and hakkers there are no blocking operations involved which you don't get with the mutex. The design is explained in [this](http://www.dalnefre.com/wp/2010/08/dining-philosophers-in-humus/) blog post.

Comment: You can avoid blocking with a mutex too though. For example, Ruby's mutexes have `lock` and `try_lock`. `lock` blocks, but `try_lock` doesn't and you just try again later.

Comment: [This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882512.aspx#id0400008) uses `Concurrency::join` to wait on multiple messages. Sounds like this is an extension to actors.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured it out with some help. I wasn't modeling the state correctly. Here's the correct solution, using a waiter: https://gist.github.com/egonSchiele/5573023

Comment: You are right about try_lock however, using actors means that you don't have to deal with such low level concurrency constructs. This is particularly important when building bigger applications.

Comment: In addition using actors with remoting capabilities (like Akka and Celluloid) means that you can easily distribute the problem over multiple machines which you don't get with mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of actors is not to have any locks in order not to run into deadlocks or other problems due to incorrect synchronization. So using locks in conjunction with actors makes you bounce back to the kind of problems actors were intended to get around. The problem is that there is a race for free forks and hence shared data. Actors work very well when there isn't any shared data. You can share simple shared data for example with the use of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap, which is lock free and sufficient for this kind of problem.

Now ConcurrentHashMap does not send an event in case some philosopher put down a fork. I once implemented a simple ConcurrentMap that let's you register events, see [ConcurrentEventMap](https://github.com/oplohmann/LambdaQueues/blob/master/src/main/java/org/objectscape/lambdaqueues/util/ConcurrentEventMap.java). Have a look at [MemoizingEventCalculatorTest](https://github.com/oplohmann/LambdaQueues/blob/master/src/test/java/org/objectscape/lambdaqueues/MemoizingEventCalculatorTest.java) to see how it is used. Getting this code to run requires JDK8, which you can download from [here](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/).

This ConcurrentEventMap is more of a temporary kludge. I'm working on getting a better implementation using ScalaSTM (see http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/). This may also be an option for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought too. Turns out I wasn't modeling the shared state correctly using actors. Check out my solution [here](https://gist.github.com/egonSchiele/5573023). Also see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/celluloid-ruby/VmFLL2mEPCs) on the Celluloid mailing list. I like STM, and I wanted to compare Actors and STM for this problem, hence this question.

Comment: Actors and STM fit very well together. If you look at Akka you see that they use ScalaSTM as well. STM is based on some kind of optimistic locking. So when there are more readers than writers, actors and STM work very well. If the number of writers is high you reach the limits of STM in case you can't get the number of writers down by changing concept/design.